# Multiple sorting with ascending and descending in Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, sorting, parse-platform

I have the following Result Class in Parse:

```
score <Number>  |  miliseconds <Number>
50              |  500
100             |  10000
100             |  20000
50              |  1000
50              |  2000
100             |  99999
```

I'm trying to sort descending by score first and then ascending by miliseconds

First try:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Result')
query.descending('score')
query.ascending('time')
return query.find()
```

And I get this:

```
score <Number>  |  miliseconds <Number>
50              |  500
50              |  1000
50              |  2000
100             |  10000
100             |  20000
100             |  99999
```

Second try:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Result')
query.ascending('time')
query.descending('score')
return query.find()
```

Result:

```
score <Number>  |  miliseconds <Number>
100             |  99999
100             |  10000
100             |  20000
50              |  500
50              |  1000
50              |  2000
```

What am I expecting?

I'm expecting to have a result like this:

```
score <Number>  |  miliseconds <Number>
100             |  10000
100             |  20000
100             |  99999
50              |  500
50              |  1000
50              |  2000
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Result')
query.descending('score')
query.addAscending('time')
return query.find()
```

The thing is to *add* another sorting condition, not overriding pervious one.

Comment: I don't know about that. Thank you very much